# Extract number between bracket and colon

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression to extract number **513922** from this string.

> Error detected (513922: settings can not be applied.), param d1=0.0, d2=0.0 in operation mode

Comment: `(?<=\()[0-9]+(?=:)`?

Comment: It may be you can format the question, and to provide the good and bad string examples, so we understand what to regexp has to match. And then to provide the regexp code you've been trying and failed with?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko can I be an apprentice?

Comment: Your question is essentially _a set of requirements_. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on *regular expression*:

```
 string source = 
   "Error detected (513922: settings can not be applied.), param d1=0.0, d2=0.0 in...";

 // 513922
 string result = Regex.Match(source, @"(?<=\()[0-9]+(?=:)").Value;
 // if you want integer representation:
 int number = int.Parse(result);
```

Comment: If there is no match, the code will throw an exception. Also, lookarounds can be replaced with consuming patterns and the part we need can be *captured* - that would be much more efficient.